# Breaking a While loop

Tags: functions

A simple example to illustrate what I'm talking about:

```
m=0;
While[m<=50,
m=m+1;
p=m]
```

The result is:

```
m=51
p=51
```

In languages like Fortran or VB, the loop would stop exactly when m=51 and wouldn't do "p=m".
The result would be:

```
m=51
p=50
```

How to program Mathematica to stop exactly when the condition is met?

Comment: `While[ (m=m+1)<=50 , p=m]`.  No way Fortran auto exits a loop as you claim, by the way. ( I doubt VB does either.. )

Comment: You seem to be confusing the test condition with the body that is just  one `CompoundExpression` that will always return `m=p`.

Answer (score 4):

You may be thinking of another idiom.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_while_loop#Equivalent_constructs

```
m = 0;
While[True, m = m + 1;
 If[Not[m <= 50], Break[]];
 p = m]
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are seeking a [`For`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/For.html) loop:

```
For[m = 0, m <= 50, ++m, p = m]

{m, p}
```

> ```
> {51, 50}
> ```

However as george2079 already showed you could also use `While`:

```
m = 0;
While[(++m) <= 50, p = m]

{m, p}
```

> ```
> {51, 50}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 m=0;
 While[m<=50,p=m;
   m=m+1
 ]
```

Reversing the order of the last 2 instructions fixes the problem.

Comment: another valid approach. don't know why the downvote..